# Running bash scripts within newly created folders based on file names

Tags: python, bash

I'm not sure even where to start.

I have a list of output files from a program, lets call them foo. They are numbered outputs like foo_1.out

I'd like to make a directory for each file, move the file to its directory, run a bash script within that directory, take the output from each script, copy it to the root directory as a concatenated single file.

I understand that this is not a forum for "hey, do my work for me", I'm honestly trying to learn. Any suggestions on where to look are sincerely appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look up the documentation for the python modules `os` - specifically `os.path` and a couple of others - and `subprocess` which can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) and [here](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) respectively.

Without wanting to do it all for you as you stated - you'll be wanting to do something like:

```
for f in filelist:
    [pth, ext] = os.path.splitext(f)
    os.mkdir(pth)
    out = subprocess.Popen(SCRIPTNAME, stdout=...)
    # and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all files in a directory or make folders, check out the [os module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).  Specifically, try `os.listdir` and `os.mkdir`

To copy files, you could either manually open each file, copy the contents to a string, and rewrite it to a different file.  Alternatively, look at the [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) module

To run bash scripts, use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) library.

All three of those should be a part of python's standard library.